# ObservableCollection returning wrong type

Tags: wpf, vb.net

For some reason I'm adding each item in the findall function to the observable collection, and I am getting back "groupname" in my listbox.. instead of the actual name of the group.

```
    Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
    Dim qbeGroup As New GroupPrincipal(ctx)
    Dim srch As New PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup)
    For Each item In srch.FindAll()
        GroupsList.Add(New groups With { _
          .name = item.Name
          })
    Next
```

Below is my simple observablecollection

```
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return m_name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_name As String
```

Is there something else I need to be doing to return the actual string?

Edit: Xaml

```
  <ListBox x:Name="lbAvGroups_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="470" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="355" Margin="392,35,0,0"/>
```

I do the binding in code-behind, so this is what my binding looks like.

```
 Public View As ICollectionView
 Public GroupsList As new ObservableCollection(Of groups)

 View = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GroupsList)
 lbAvGroups.ItemsSource = View
```

Comment: What does your XAML code for the list box look like?

Comment: Edited to show xaml, and relevant code for the binding. If I add messagebox.show(item.name) in the for loop, it will show the actual name.

Comment: Try adding `lbAvGroups.DisplayMemberPath = "name"` - I believe it will use whatever is returned by `ToString` otherwise.

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind a `ListBox` to a list of objects it will, by default, display the value returned by calling `ToString` on the objects.  You can either define the `ItemTemplate` for the `ListBox`, or for simple text display you can set the `DisplayMemberPath` to the name of the property you want to show.  So, in your case you can add

```
lbAvGroups.DisplayMemberPath = "name"
```

when binding the list box to display the `name` property of each item.